# Optional Source in MS Access Union Query - to skip it if not available

Tags: ms-access, union-all

Hi I need to solve an issue with dynamic data sources in MS Access union query.
My data base has dynamic sources month over month for example:

Source 1 is constant but Source 2 and Source 3 are dynamic - one month is available but the other not and this repeats over the time. I have an union query combining these three queries / sources but when some of them is missing an error occurs.

I am looking for advice how to achieve optional source logic without changing the query itself and without putting an empty file with the respective name instead.

Is there an logic that tries if second source available to use it but if no just to skip it?

Query 1 (Source1)
UNION ALL
**/Optional/** Select Query 2 (Source2)
UNION ALL
**/Optional/** Select Query 3 (Source3)

Thank you!

I was searching for syntax (key word like TRY but it did not work).
I found the following example but didn't manage to run properly.

begin try
--your critical commands
end try
begin catch
-- is necessary write somethink like this
select ''
end cath

Comment: Tables or queries should not appear or vanish like this. Re-think your table structure. If you have one table per month: this data should all go into one single table, with month being a column. If this data comes monthly from outside: insert it into this table.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and advice Andre. In fact it is for very specific purpose that’s why I am looking for such a solution.

Comment: Create the union query by VBA code (database.createquerydef) according to the situation.

Comment: Well, perhaps you can be a bit more specific about that specific purpose ;) then people could give you better advice. There is no Try Catch in Access SQL, so if you need it dynamic, you'll have to create the SQL with VBA. But this is most probably not the best solution.

Comment: If your skills are up to the very simple task of cutting and pasting to make new union queries out of the original then you can run saved queries in vba.  Create versions for all the combinations of queries you need to union.  Then You can use the immediate window (CTRL-G) to test running the saved queries and help figure out how to test if a query should be omitted given your table structure.  If necessary, like if you have other users, encapsulate all this into a Query loading form which you can use instead of the immediate window if you must.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, it is not possible to check this in the query but you can use VBA to check if the table exists:

```
If Not IsNull(DlookUp("Name","MSysObjects","Name='TableName' And Type In (1,4,6)")) Then
    'Table Exists
```

Based on this result you can build your query and execute it or you create for each possible outcome a separate query and execute the one which fits.